# How to reject bad segments when working with long epochs in MNE Python

Tags: mne-python

I am doing a social cognition experiment with eeg for my thesis, and in my experiment I am working with long trials of 25 seconds.
This means that if I use any automatic rejection function to reject bad segments, it will remove a large amount of my data as the entire epoch is being dropped when using both mne.annotations or autoreject. Any suggestions on how to remove bad segments in my 25 seconds long epochs without removing entire epochs?

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this?